# Mongodb Atlas m0

Tags: mongodb

I am starting with mongodb atlas and I am a bit lost.
I would like to follow the tutorial:

https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/tutorial-series-getting-started-with-mongodb-atlas

I am on the 2 tutorial and I am not able to see the build cluster UI wich come at 2:30

When I come in the UI of cloud manager I have a "New deployment" button and when I click on it I have a complete configuration. But I would like the simple one. Does anyone tries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have MongoDB Cloud Manager and MongoDB Atlas groups associated with the same login.

If you see a "New Deployment" button rather than a "Build a New Cluster", you are looking at a MongoDB Cloud Manager group rather than a MongoDB Atlas group. The logo at the top left of your page should also indicate whether the currently selected group is Cloud Manager or Atlas.

To add a MongoDB Atlas group:

> In Cloud Manager, click on your user name in the upper-right hand corner and select **My Groups**. Click the **Add Group** button.
>
> The **Create a New Group** screen provides you the choice to create either an Atlas group or a Cloud Manager group. Select MongoDB Atlas to create a new Atlas group and switch to the **Clusters** view in Atlas. To add clusters to the new group, continue to [Create a Cluster](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/create-new-cluster/).

The above steps are from the MongoDB Atlas FAQ: [As an existing MongoDB Cloud Manager account holder, how do I create a new MongoDB Atlas group?](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/faq/#cm-create-atlas-group).